# React-Native – undefined is not an object (“evaluating _react3.default.PropTypes.shape”)

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am going through a tutorial on React Native that uses the 'Navigator' object, which apparently has been deprecated since the tutorial was posted.  There is some errata included that supposedly has a fix to the code, but that still doesn't prevent the above error.  I've searched other questions on this topic, but the solutions don't work for me.

I've installed `'react-native-deprecated-custom-components'` and `'prop-types'` and included them in the code below.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';
import { Navigator } from 'react-native-deprecated-custom-components';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Quote from './quote';

const zenImage = require ('./assets/zen_circle.png');

const navScene = {
  sceneContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'stretch'
  }
}

export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  // Following two lines of code were included in the errata, but cause
  // an unexpected token error right on the first period below.
  // Navigator.sceneStyle = {navScene.sceneContainer};
  // sceneStyle={styles.sceneContainer};
  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        initialRoute={{ name: 'StartScreen' }}
        renderScene={(route, navigator) => {
          return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
              {/*<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => {alert('I was pressed!')}}>
                <Image source={zenImage} style={styles.buttonImage} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <Text style={styles.readyText}>I'm ready to relax...</Text>*/}
              <Quote quoteText="Amazing quote!" quoteSource="- Great source!"/>
            </View>
          );
        }}
      />

    );
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: did you try rm -rf node_modules && npm i ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstall the already installed react-native-deprecated-custom-components like below.

```
npm uninstall --save react-native-deprecated-custom-components
```

After that install it as follows.

```
npm install --save https://github.com/facebookarchive/react-native-custom-components.git
```

Now run your application and you issue will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

most of the times these errors happen because of the cached stuff..

try this command and check:

`cd android & gradlew clean & cd .. & rm -rf node_modules/ & npm cache clean --force & yarn install & react-native run-android`

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem, it seems like they haven't updated their npm package but their github branch has the proptypes changes, throw this into your package.json:

```
"react-native-deprecated-custom-components": "github:facebookarchive/react-native-custom-components",
```

Comment: Did you re-install it? `rm -rf node_modules/ && npm install`